# Is it possible to integrate MIRTH with Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration, mirth, hl7-v3

I was looking around the websites to look for MIRTH and Apache Camel integration but cannot find any clue yet.
Problem is Apache Camel HL7 component does not provide support for HL7 V3 but HL7 V2 using HAPI library.

Now we are looking to use MIRTH and try integrating it with Apache Camel, again there is no component to connect to MIRTH.

Need advise how to achieve it using Apache Camel.

Comment: Are you asking for HL7 v3 support which is much different than v2 due the XML change. If so there is no v3 out of the box from Apache Camel

Comment: yes, you are right i.e. HL7 v3 support is required. if not any java library or MIRTH connectivity with apache camel possible ?

Comment: No, there is no out of the box hl7 v3 or mirth from Apache Camel. You can ask Mirth if they would consider providing a Camel adapter in their software offerings

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel supports a number of communication mechanisms such as HTTP, ActiveMQ, SOAP, etc. The same is Mirth Connect that handles TCP/MLLP, File, JMS, FTP, HTTP, SOAP and direct database access. So you have enough options to integrate these two.

None of these integration engines provide readily available support for HL7v**3**.